# Is there any (locally) conserved charges associated to gauge symmetries?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, conservation-laws, gauge-theory, noethers-theorem, gauge-invariance

I'm currently in my second year of master.

From what I understand, in QFT, [Noether's first theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) implies that for any continuous symmetry (i.e. associated to a $n$-dimensional Lie group $G$, $n\geq 1$), there are $n$ corresponding conserved currents and thus $n$ conserved charges.

From [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/316345/), I understand that, for gauge symmetries, the symmetry group associated to $G$ is an infinite-dimmensional Lie group. So, can we apply Noether's theorem this symmetry group? Does it give an infinite number of conserved charges?

Comment: Related: [Noether charge of local symmetries](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/66092/2451) and links therein.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since most of the answers in the post mentioned by Qmechanic are either too technical or come to the wrong conclusion, I will try to give a simple yet precise answer. I will consider Maxwell theory as an example.

Let's try to apply the Noether's theorem to gauge symmetries of the Maxwell theory, i.e. $A_\mu\to A_\mu +\partial_\mu\lambda$ for arbitrary function $\lambda(x)$. This symmetry is also called a *local* symmetry, as you can take $\lambda$ to be non-vanishing inside any arbitrary region and zero outside.

Now you may start with the Lagrangian ${\cal L}=-\frac14 F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$ and compute the standard Noether current for the gauge transformation parametrized by the function $\lambda$. You find
\begin{align}
J^\mu_\lambda=F^{\mu\nu}\partial_\nu\lambda
\end{align}
You can check that the current is conserved $\partial_\mu J_\lambda^\mu=0$ only after using the equations of motion $\partial_\mu F^{\mu\nu}=0$. Now the charge Noether charge over a hypersurface $\Sigma$ (which can be a constant time surface) is given as usual by
\begin{align}
Q_\lambda=\int_\Sigma t_\mu J^\mu_\lambda=\int_\Sigma t_\mu F^{\mu\nu}\partial_\nu\lambda
\end{align}
where $t_\mu$ is the unit normal to $\Sigma$. Now the crucial step is that upon integration by parts and using the field equations we can write the charge as a boundary integral
\begin{align}
Q_\lambda=\oint_{\partial\Sigma} t_\mu n_\nu \big(F^{\mu\nu}\lambda\big)
\end{align}
where $\partial\Sigma$ is the boundary of $\Sigma$ and $n_\mu$ is the unit normal tangent to $\Sigma$ and normal to its boundary $\partial \Sigma$. Note that if $\Sigma$ is the constant time hypersurface, then we have $t_\mu n_\nu F^{\mu\nu}=n\cdot E$, the normal electric field to the boundary.

Now if $\Sigma$, has no boundary, e.g. if it is a 3 sphere $S^3$, then the charge is identically zero. This is what usually people refer to when talking about the charge of gauge symmetries. However, if the space has a boundary, then the charge is non-zero. This can naturally happen if your problem is defined in a finite region of space (e.g. in Casimir effect), or if you consider flat spacetime with natural boundary conditions $A_\mu\sim 1/r$, then you have nontrivial charges if $\lambda\big\vert_{\partial \Sigma}\neq 0$.

The conclusions above are true for any field theory with local symmetries (including gauge theory and gravity). The charges reduce to boundary integrals. This is proven in Barnich, Brandt 2001 ([here](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0111246))
To read more about the latter case, you may see [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.03616) reference as an starting point and continue with more advanced topics in the references therein.